# Converting weird timestamp with php date() for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, timestamp

**The timestamp in question `2018-02-08T09:51:54+00:00`**

Im using the SendinBlue woocommerce plugin to send my store emails and handle the templates but when inserting the order date, which the plugin gets by means of `$order->get_date_created()`

the problem is when using date I get the debug error

`date() expects parameter 2 to be integer`

im assuming this is because of the `T`, `+` and `:`?

Im still not sure if there is a woocommerce trick I've missed with formatting the date or if this is something the SendinBlue plugin is doing?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The format is defined in the PHP `DATE_ATOM` constant. You can convert times like this to timestamps with: `DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM, $your_date)->getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two similar ways:

1) With Woocommerce:

The [`WC_Order` `get_date_created()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_date_created) method returns a [`WC_Datetime`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_DateTime.html) object. You can re-format it using the [`WC_Datetime` `date()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_DateTime.html#_date) for example this way:

```
// Using '2018-02-08T09:51:54+00:00' timestamp
echo $order->get_date_created()->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and will display: `2018-02-08 09:51:54`.

---

2) With PHP:

Or you can reformat any "weird" timestamp using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function inside the PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function using the available [PHP `date()` formatting arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For example:

```
$timestamp = $order->get_date_created(); // Using '2018-02-08T09:51:54+00:00' timestamp
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timestamp));
```

will also display: `2018-02-08 09:51:54`.